# startActivityForResult dont return to previous fragment when choose in gallary

Tags: android, android-fragments, startactivityforresult

I have 3 fragment fragment A fragment B and Fragment C

In fragment C that's where i intent the ACTION Pick intent, and when i select the image this will return
[Empty activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J26Dw.png)  instead return to fragment c to display the image i selected

This is my code

```
    submitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(intent ,100);
        }
    });
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    if(resultCode==RESULT_OK && requestCode==100)
    {
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        imageView.setImageURI(uri);
    }
}'
```

Comment: Apparently your activity with the fragment was killed while the gui for action pick was on top of it. Use onSaveInstanceState to save the state.

Comment: @blackapps can u help me what it code looks like because it return null